# Find custom point coordinates with Forge

Tags: reactjs, properties, coordinates, autodesk-forge, database-metadata

I work with Autodesk Forge (node.js, javascript (worked with it a little), React (completely new !)).
I have a rectangle 3D object. At each corner is a point with real world coordinates (lat, lon, z).

These coordinates can be displayed with the property panel in the viewer.

I want to access them from the code, but I cannot find them anywhere.

At first, I thought they would be at :

```
window.NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().metadata
```

but nothing !

[image]

Here is a picture of what I can see in the viewer. Since I can see them in the property panel, I should be able to access them !

I tried to use this :

```
window.NOP_VIEWER.model.getBulkProperties('1', 
function(properties){console.log(properties);},
function(error){console.log(error);})
```

It returns an amazingly long list of field names (if think that's it).
When I try to put it in a variable it returns 'undefined'. So I cannot access what is inside anyway.

Also tried getProperties() but I think I did not write it in the right way, it doesn't work either.

I also tried som GET request to find the object properties, but all I got was this :

```
{
"data": {
    "type": "objects",
    "objects": [
        {
            "objectid": 1,
            "name": "Model",
            "objects": [
                {
                    "objectid": 2691,
                    "name": "Sols",
                    "objects": [
                        {
                            "objectid": 2692,
                            "name": "Sol",
                            "objects": [
                                {
                                    "objectid": 2693,
                                    "name": "Dalle en béton - 250 mm",
                                    "objects": [
                                        {
                                            "objectid": 2694,
                                            "name": "Sol [236041]"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "objectid": 2711,
                    "name": "Modèles génériques",
                    "objects": [
                        {
                            "objectid": 2712,
                            "name": "Point_Georeferencement",
                            "objects": [
                                {
                                    "objectid": 2713,
                                    "name": "Point_Georeferencement",
                                    "objects": [
                                        {
                                            "objectid": 2714,
                                            "name": "Point_Georeferencement [236831]"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "objectid": 2715,
                                            "name": "Point_Georeferencement [236836]"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "objectid": 2716,
                                            "name": "Point_Georeferencement [236843]"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "objectid": 2717,
                                            "name": "Point_Georeferencement [236846]"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

But I cannot find a way to access the points' names or their values !

Can anyone help with this, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOP_VIEWER` is a global variable to access the current Viewer. From that you can call:

`.getProperties()`: this requires 1 dbId, an easy way to try it is with:

```
NOP_VIEWER.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, function (e) {
    e.dbIdArray.forEach(function (dbId) {
        NOP_VIEWER.getProperty(dbId, function (props) {
            console.log(props)
        })
    })
});
```

`.model.getBulkProperties()`: this received an array of elements and just return the properties you specify:

```
NOP_VIEWER.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, function (e) {
    viewer.model.getBulkProperties(e.dbIdArray, ['RefX', 'RefY'], function (elements) {
        elements.forEach(function(element){
            console.log(element);
        })
    })
});
```

And you may also combine it with `.search()` ([see here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/getbulkproperties-method)) or by [enumerating leaf nodes](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/enumerating-leaf-nodes-viewer).

Comment: Indeed, I had trouble to access the dbId, but yes, it works fine (forgot to publish my answer earlier).

Comment: I still get "undefined" value for NOP_VIEWER if I use it as a variable in my code. I am working with Typescript, so I tried declaring it like this: var NOP_VIEWER: any = {}; and even like this: var NOP_VIEWER = (window as any).NOP_VIEWER; but nothing worked. Do you know what the problem might be?